# Adding an image with C3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, c3.js

I am trying to add an image to my chart made in C3.js

I need to have the image sit in the center of the graph, and I have 6 of these graphs on one page.

[image: Example of what I have now.]
I want to replace the text of transport etc with an image instead.

Here is the code I am using to generate the graphs.

```
    var transport = c3.generate({

    data: {
        columns: [
            ['Labour', labourLikes],
            ['Greens', greensLikes],
            ['National', nationalLikes],
            ['United Future', unitedfutureLikes],
            ['ACT', actLikes],
            ['NZ First', nzfirstLikes],
        ],
        type: 'donut',
        colors: {
            Labour: '#D82C20',
            Greens: '#00C760',
            National: '#0B6FAA',
            'United Future': '#40003F',
            ACT: '#FFDE00',
            'NZ First': '#000',
        },
        onclick: function (d, i) { console.log("onclick", d, i); },
        onmouseover: function (d, i) { console.log("onmouseover", d, i); },
        onmouseout: function (d, i) { console.log("onmouseout", d, i); }
    },
    donut: {
        title: "Education"
    },
    legend: {
        show: false
    },
    bindto: '#education'

});
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can insert an image into the central node of donut chart - **.c3-chart-arcs**

```
oninit: function() {
    var element = this.selectChart[0][0]
    var center = d3
      .select(element)
      .select('.c3-chart-arcs')
      .insert('image',':first-child')
      .attr('x', -75)
      .attr('y', -75)
      .attr('width', 150)
      .attr('height', 150)
      .attr('xlink:href', 'http://pngimages.net/sites/default/files/small-png-image-20665.png')
}
```

See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Dimmy/sstz3z82/1/).